Mapstruct Spring boot cyclic dependency
so i have a social network project with entities such as User and Post. I have a UserResponse and a PostResponse too, so im trying to map them using mapstruct but im getting this cyclic dependency error.
User:
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String bio;

    @Lob
    private byte[] profilePictureUrl;
    private String role;
    private long followerCount;
    private long followingCount;
    private String accountPrivacy; // public, private

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private VerificationCode verificationCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Like> likes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Reel> reels;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Story> stories;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserEntity> followers;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserEntity> followings;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserEntity> pendingFollowRequests;

}

User Response:
public class UserResponse {
    private String username;
    private String fullName;
    private String bio;
    private byte[] profilePicture;
    private String accountPrivacy;
    private long followerCount;
    private long followingCount;

    private List<PostResponse> posts;
    private List<ReelResponse> reels;
    private List<Story> stories;
    private List<CommentResponse> comments;
    private Set<LikeResponse> likes;
    private Set<UserResponse> followers;
    private Set<UserResponse> followings;
}

user mapper:
@Service
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.SETTER,
        uses = {PostMapper.class, ReelMapper.class, StoryMapper.class, LikeMapper.class, CommentMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Lazy
    @Named("userResponseToUser")
    @Mapping(source = "profilePicture", target = "profilePictureUrl")
    @Mapping(source = "posts", target = "posts", qualifiedByName = "postResponseToPost")
    @Mapping(source = "reels", target = "reels", qualifiedByName = "reelResponseToReel")
    @Mapping(source = "comments", target = "comments", qualifiedByName = "commentResponseToComment")
    @Mapping(source = "likes", target = "likes", qualifiedByName = "likeResponseToLike")
    @Mapping(source = "followers", target = "followers", qualifiedByName = "userResponseToUser")
    @Mapping(source = "followings", target = "followings", qualifiedByName = "userResponseToUser")
    UserEntity userResponseToUser( UserResponse userResponse);

    @Lazy
    @Named("userToUserResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "profilePictureUrl", target = "profilePicture")
    @Mapping(source = "posts", target = "posts", qualifiedByName = "postToPostResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "reels", target = "reels", qualifiedByName = "reelToReelResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "comments", target = "comments", qualifiedByName = "commentToCommentResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "likes", target = "likes", qualifiedByName = "likeToLikeResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "followers", target = "followers", qualifiedByName = "userToUserResponse")
    @Mapping(source = "followings", target = "followings", qualifiedByName = "userToUserResponse")
    UserResponse userToUserResponse( UserEntity userEntity);

}

so what should i do here to fix this problem?
I have tried these solutions with @Named and such, even used Injection strategy of type setter yet it still exists
